# XSSFReader.SheetIterator.hasNext() returns false on an Excel SS with three sheets

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, sax

I am digging into the details of parsing XLSX files with SAX/Apache POI. I built a class similar to the [How To](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/how-to.html), and ran into an issue with the XSSFReader.SheetIterator returning false even when it's obvious there are three sheets in the document.

```
public void processAllSheets(String xlFile) throws Exception {
        OPCPackage opcPackage = OPCPackage.open(xlFile);
        XSSFReader reader = new XSSFReader(opcPackage);
        SharedStringsTable sst = (SharedStringsTable) reader.getSharedStringsTable();
        for (int i = 0; i < sst.getUniqueCount(); i++) {
            RichTextString s = sst.getItemAt(i);
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        XMLReader parser = fetchSheetParser(sst);
        Iterator<InputStream> sheets = reader.getSheetsData();
        ArrayList<String> sheetNames = new ArrayList<>();
        if (sheets instanceof XSSFReader.SheetIterator) {
            XSSFReader.SheetIterator sheetIterator = (XSSFReader.SheetIterator) sheets;
            while (sheetIterator.hasNext()) {
                InputStream dummy = sheetIterator.next();
                sheetNames.add(sheetIterator.getSheetName());
                dummy.close();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sheetNames.toString());
        XSSFReader.SheetIterator sheetIterator = (XSSFReader.SheetIterator) sheets;
        while (sheetIterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("Processing new sheet:\n");
            InputStream sheet = sheetIterator.next();
            InputSource sheetSource = new InputSource(sheet);
            parser.parse(sheetSource);
            sheet.close();
            xmlCache = handler.getCache();
            if (!xmlCache.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.printf("Items in cache: %s", xmlCache.size());
            } else {
                System.out.println("XML cache is empty.");
            }
        }
```

The last while loop is skipped completely, though when I look at the ***sheetIterator*** object in the debugger the ***sheetMap*** plainly has 3 sheets:
[image: Debugger screen shot]
I'm new to this kind of lower-level hacking of Excel files, so I'm stumped. Thanks!

Comment: "similar to the How To": No, totally different from that. `XSSFReader.getSheetsData` gets an `Iterator` which in your code iterates to it's end while reading the sheet names. After that this `Iterator` is at its end and cannot iterate from begin again.

Comment: @AxelRichter You are absolutely correct, I didn't see that. Refreshing the iterator with another call to reader.getSheetsData() solved the problem.